# Как создать много текстовых полей в Tkinter (Python) и взять из них значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, tkinter, криптография

Мне нужно написать программу на Python 3, которая поможет расшифровать текст зашифрованный моноалфавитным шифром (шифр простой замены).

На данный момент программа умеет спрашивать какой текстовый файл посмотреть, считает каждый символ в тексте и выводит в консоль их количество. Я бы хотел, чтобы с помощью графических элементов библиотеки Tkinter можно было подставить одни символы вместе других. Например, чтобы буква А в тексте заменилась на С, О на Т и так далее.
Я могу только вручную создать поля ввода и также считать их содержимое, но выглядит это ужасно.

**Можно ли создать поля ввода и считать их содержимое циклом** или вроде того?
Полный код моей программы:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import operator

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
quantity = {}
filename = "-"
Text = ''
changed_symbols= {}


def selecting_file():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file",
                                          filetypes=(("text files", "*.txt"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    try:
        CipherText = open(filename, 'r')
        Text = CipherText.read().lower()
        CipherText.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Неверное имя файла")
        raise SystemExit(0)

    for i in range(len(alphabet)):
        quantity[alphabet[i]] = 0

    for letter in Text:
        if letter in quantity.keys():
            quantity[letter] += 1

    sorted_characters = sorted(quantity.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    for i in sorted_characters:
        print(i[0], '-', i[1])


def window_deleted():
    print('Окно закрыто')
    root.quit()


def change_symbols():
    CorrespondingLetters = {}


root = Tk()
root.title("Decryptor")
root.geometry("400x550+300+300")
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', window_deleted)

selectfile = Button(text="Select file", command=selecting_file).place(relx=0.5, y=10)
ChangeLettersButton = Button(text="Change letters", command=change_symbols,).place(relx=0.5, y=500)

a = Label(text="a").place(x=50, y=50)
letters_a = Entry().place(x=80, y=50, width=30)

b = Label(text="b").place(x=50, y=100)
letters_b = Entry().place(x=80, y=100, width=30)

c = Label(text="c").place(x=50, y=150)
letters_c = Entry().place(x=80, y=150, width=30)

d = Label(text="d").place(x=50, y=200)
letters_d = Entry().place(x=80, y=200, width=30)

e = Label(text="e").place(x=50, y=250)
letters_e = Entry().place(x=80, y=250, width=30)

f = Label(text="f").place(x=50, y=300)
letters_f = Entry().place(x=80, y=300, width=30)

g = Label(text="g").place(x=50, y=350)
letters_g = Entry().place(x=80, y=350, width=30)

h = Label(text="h").place(x=50, y=400)
letters_h = Entry().place(x=80, y=400, width=30)

i = Label(text="i").place(x=50, y=450)
letters_i = Entry().place(x=80, y=450, width=30)
# ------------------------------------------------

j = Label(text="j").place(x=150, y=50)
letters_j = Entry().place(x=180, y=50, width=30)

k = Label(text="k").place(x=150, y=100)
letters_k = Entry().place(x=180, y=100, width=30)

l = Label(text="l").place(x=150, y=150)
letters_l = Entry().place(x=180, y=150, width=30)

m = Label(text="m").place(x=150, y=200)
letters_m = Entry().place(x=180, y=200, width=30)

n = Label(text="n").place(x=150, y=250)
letters_n = Entry().place(x=180, y=250, width=30)

o = Label(text="o").place(x=150, y=300)
letters_o = Entry().place(x=180, y=300, width=30)

p = Label(text="p").place(x=150, y=350)
letters_p = Entry().place(x=180, y=350, width=30)

q = Label(text="q").place(x=150, y=400)
letters_q = Entry().place(x=180, y=400, width=30)

r = Label(text="r").place(x=150, y=450)
letters_r = Entry().place(x=180, y=450, width=30)
# ------------------------------------------------
s = Label(text="s").place(x=250, y=50)
letters_s = Entry().place(x=280, y=50, width=30)

t = Label(text="t").place(x=250, y=100)
letters_t = Entry().place(x=280, y=100, width=30)

u = Label(text="u").place(x=250, y=150)
letters_u = Entry().place(x=280, y=150, width=30)

v = Label(text="v").place(x=250, y=200)
letters_v = Entry().place(x=280, y=200, width=30)

w = Label(text="w").place(x=250, y=250)
letters_w = Entry().place(x=280, y=250, width=30)

x = Label(text="x").place(x=250, y=300)
letters_x = Entry().place(x=280, y=300, width=30)

y = Label(text="y").place(x=250, y=350)
letters_y = Entry().place(x=280, y=350, width=30)

z = Label(text="z").place(x=250, y=400)
letters_z = Entry().place(x=280, y=400, width=30)
# -------------------------------------------------
messageVar = Message(root).place(x=350, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вместо `raise SystemExit(0)` просто используйте `quit()` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто оберните весь код в цикл:

```
pos = 0
x = 50
y = 50

try:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(9):
            letter = alphabet[pos]

            label = Label(text=letter)
            entry = Entry()

            label.place(x=x, y=y)
            entry.place(x=x + 30, y=y, width=30)

            pos += 1
            y += 50

        y = 50
        x += 100

# Ленивый способ выйти из циклов - когда `pos` переберет все символы из alphabet
except IndexError:
    pass
```

---

Заметил что у вас есть переменные с виджетами такие как `d` и `letters_d`. Наверное, вы хотели бы к ним после обращаться, чтобы это было возможным создайте им переменные, например через `globals`:

```
...
        label = Label(text=letter)
        label.place(x=x, y=y)

        entry = Entry()
        entry.place(x=x+30, y=y, width=30)

        globals()['label_' + letter] = label
        globals()['letter_' + letter] = entry
...
```

Тестирование:

```
...
print(label_a)   # .!label
print(letter_a)  # .!entry2
```

---

**PS.**

Переменные с `place` имеют мало смысла

```
<переменная> = <виджет>.place(<...>)
```

Потому что в переменную попадет не ссылка на виджет, а результат выполнения `place`, а именно `None`.

Думаю, это не то, что вам нужно. Лучше тогда так:

```
<переменная> = <виджет>
<переменная>.place(<...>)
```

Comment: Как я могу обращаться к переменным, чтобы, допустим, узнать какое значение они хранят?
На примере кода:
globals()['label_' + letter] = label
            globals()['letter_' + letter] = entry
            print('label_' + letter + ' = ' + ["letter_"+letter])
            pos += 1
            y += 50
Выдаёт ошибку TypeError: must be str, not list
Я знаю, что в цикле переменная, когда только поля ввода созданы, переменные  (напр. label_c) пустые, но он же вроде тогда должен выводить пустоту?

Comment: `print('label_' + letter + ' = ' + ["letter_"+letter])` тут вы к строке прибавляете список, что и вызывает ошибку, тогда уж так: `print('label_' + letter + ' = ' + "letter_"+letter)`. Переменные пустые или `None`? `None` не могут быть, т.к. код с `place` подправил. `Как я могу обращаться к переменным, чтобы, допустим, узнать какое значение они хранят?` попробуйте вызвать `get()`, например `print(letter_a.get())`, а так, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос